# Office365 My apps launcher and Azure AD endpoint v2.0

Tags: office365, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-active-directory

Does the Office 365 "My Apps" launcher [see image here](http://jthakeblob.blob.core.windows.net/blog/2015/05/applauncher.jpg) is compatible with the applications registered using the new Azure AD endpoint, the so-called [Azure AD v2.0](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-appmodel-v2-overview/)?

I am migrating to this new endpoint and its promising new  capabilities but this feature is mandatory to us.

Comment: I meant that this is mandatory for us because we distribute through the Office Store. The fact that your app is listed under "My Apps" launcher is part of the requirements https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220035.aspx see rule 4.12.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on empiric testing, doesn't look like the O365 App Launcher supports applications registered for the new v2 endpoint.

While my Access Panel (myapps.microsoft.com) shows both v1 and v2 apps, only the v1 apps show up in the O365 app.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. I came to the same conclusion. I voted you up but will wait a little for an "official" answer before marking it as accepted.

Comment: I am accepting your answer that confirms the behavior I have noticed too.

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind the app tiles not appearing in the App Launcher is due to an issue that causes the 'homepage' value to not get set when creating a new application in the apps.dev application registration portal. This value is used as the redirect for the app tile, so it needs to be set before it can display. You can set the value by taking the following steps.

1. Head to the graph explorer - https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/graph-explorer#
2. Sign in using the same account that has registered the app in the Application Registration Portal
3. Using the 'Beta' version GET the '/beta/applications' endpoint

This displays all apps that are associated with your account, you'll need the 'id' value for the app you'd like to change (NOTE. this is different from the App-ID, which is just your Client-ID)

4. Again using the 'Beta' version of the API run a PATCH on the '/beta/applications/' endpoint - where id is the value from step 3
   In the body of the request have the following
   {"homepage":"http://your.login.url"}

Once you've done that any logins using your app will cause it to show in the My Apps Launcher

Comment: Great. This is a workaround. But if we distribute a multi tenant Azure AD v2.0 we need to do the PATCH request automatically and any time a new user enters the system. Can this be done without any admin scope?

Comment: hmmm I see what you mean - unfortunately I haven't got any experience with the multi-tenant apps. I would assume that if the homepage string is set on the initially registered app it would come across for any of the tenants it populates in?